# One query per row or only one query on Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm dealing with some legacy code and I'not sure about what is doing this code

```
  while ($clients = $storage->likeBy(
                    'Client',
                    $criteria,
                    array('limit' => $batchSize, 'offset' => $offset))
                ) {
                    ....
                  }
```

`likeBy` function calls `doctrine` `EntitiManager` class

```
$records = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

My question is ..calling `likeBy` this way, as a while loop condition

```
while ($clients = $storage->likeBy(
                        'Client',
                        $criteria,
                        array('limit' => $batchSize, 'offset' => $offset))
                    )
```

The data is fetched one by one, one query per for every row of the result or is fetched in a single result with all result rows,(only one database query)?

Comment: the call is outside the loop so you get all the rows and then iterate over each one

Comment: ok ,but  in the second iteration is not going to take the same result?getting an infinite loop??

Comment: Why?I not sure how it works

Comment: but is the loop condition ,everytime is claled is going to get results and the loop condition is going to be true¿?

Comment: but this is for a for  loop not a while